# Condition for conormal module of commutative, Noetherian, local ring to have finite length

Tags: commutative-algebra, localization, noetherian, local-rings, ring-isomorphism

Let $A$ be a commutative, Noetherian, local ring, $O$ a discrete valuation ring and $\lambda : A \rightarrow O$ be an epimorphism. Let $p=\ker(\lambda)$, and consider the conormal $A$-module $p/p^2$. I'm reading that the condition that $p/p^2$ has finite length is equivalent to the natural map $A_p \rightarrow O_{(0)}$ (from the localization of $A$ at $p$ to the field of fractions of $O$) being an isomorphism, but why is this true? Module length is a relatively new topic for me and I cannot understand the equivalence. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: a finitely generated $A$-module has finite length iff it is annihilated by a power of the maximal ideal $m$ (proof: because $A/m$ is the only simple $A$-module).

Comment: @Mindlack so the conormal module here is annihilated by $p$, how do I know $p$ a power of the maximal ideal? And I still cannot see the equivalence with the isomorphism, can you please elaborate?

Comment: Assume $p$ is a proper subset of the maximal ideal $m$. Then $p/p^2$ has finite length iff it is annihilated by some $m^r$, ie iff $pm^r\subset p^2$ for some $p$. Localize at $p$, this implies $pA_p=0$. But $A_p/pA_p=(A/p)_{p/p}=O_{(0)}$. There are details to fill in but I’d rather you worked them out.

Comment: Oh now I understand, thanks!